# Make a Blog Template page on underscore.me with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to personalize a new theme made in underscore.me, but i can't seem to create a new template page with a loop that can show me posts of one specific category, how can i do this?

I'm gonna paste here the index.php of the underscore.me theme, witch has a generic loop, sadly, copying and pasting this loop on a template page does

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
            <header>
                <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

And this is the page.php.

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' ); ?>

            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news for you, you dont need a specific loop for a specific category.
if you have a category.php file in your theme, and assume that your category name is **"Lux Cars" with id of "35"**. if you copy your category.php as category-35.php or category-lux-cars.php (slug of your category). When you open the posts with this category. wordpress call this file and show posts in that loop. you can edit your category-35.php and add any category detail or sth.

But if you still want a loop for a specific category then you can use that code;

```html
<?php 
$args = array ( 'category' => ID, 'posts_per_page' => 5);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
 ?>
//Style Posts here
<?php endforeach; ?>
```